# How to sort strings containing day-of-week names in ascending order

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have a list of Strings containing Day-of-week name, start time and End time:

```
List<String> eventList = Database.getEventsForThisWeek();
```

Sample data:

```
Thursday (13:00 to 14:30)
Saturday (14:20 to 18:10)
Monday (09:00 to 14:25)
Saturday (11:00 to 12:30)
```

I want to sort the List such a way so that the Day-of-week is in ascending order. and if there are multiple records with the same day-of-week, then the Start time should be in ascending order too.

For example, after sorting, the above list should look like:

```
Monday (09:00 to 14:25)    
Thursday (13:00 to 14:30)
Saturday (11:00 to 12:30)
Saturday (14:20 to 18:10)
```

What is the best way to sort the List ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
List<String> dates = Arrays.asList(new String[]{
        "Thursday (13:00 to 14:30)",
        "Saturday (14:20 to 18:10)",
        "Monday (09:00 to 14:25)",
        "Saturday (11:00 to 12:30)"
});
Comparator<String> dateComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        try{
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
            Date d1 = format.parse(s1);
            Date d2 = format.parse(s2);
            if(d1.equals(d2)){
                return s1.substring(s1.indexOf(" ") + 1).compareTo(s2.substring(s2.indexOf(" ") + 1));
            }else{
                Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal1.setTime(d1);
                cal2.setTime(d2);
                return cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            }
        }catch(ParseException pe){
            throw new RuntimeException(pe);
        }
    }
};
Collections.sort(dates, dateComparator);
System.out.println(dates);
```

Comment: Hi Darshan, I'll be most grateful if you could provide the above code by using Monday as the first day of the week rather than Sunday?