# How to sort array to weekdays format android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have below json :

```
[
  {
    "id" : "12",
    "weekday": "Friday"
  },
  {
    "id" : "121",
    "weekday": "Monday"
  },
  {
    "id" : "123",
    "weekday": "Sunday"
  },
  {
    "id" : "222",
    "weekday": "Tuesday"
  }
]
```

Now i want to re-arrange it in a manner(Mon-Sun) where monday comes first and sunday comes last.

How can i do that ?

Comment: Are you using any library for your JSON (Jackson, Gson, …)?

Comment: No i am using default JSONArray to get data from my API.

Comment: I see. I think it’s an Android thing. It’s not in my desktop Java.

Comment: Are you converting this to a List of some data class? What format do you want your resulting list of items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in Kotlin, but gives you an idea of what you can do. You can create a method or property that assigns a value to each JSON model based on the weekday and then sort based on that. This is case sensitive, you could make it case insensitive as well.

```
data class Weekday(

    @field:SerializedName("weekday")
    val weekday: String,

    @field:SerializedName("id")
    val id: String
)

private val Weekday.index: Int
    get() = when (weekday) {
        "Monday" -> 0
        "Tuesday" -> 1
        "Wednesday" -> 2
        "Thursday" -> 3
        "Friday" -> 4
        "Saturday" -> 5
        "Sunday" -> 6
        else -> 7
    }

fun sort() {
    val weekdays: List<Weekday> = /* TODO */

    val result = weekdays.sortedWith(object : Comparator<Weekday> {
        override fun compare(o1: Weekday, o2: Weekday): Int {
            return o1.index.compareTo(o2.index)
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use a regular class.

Comment: In that case you would have to get the keys for the map (this is a list), and then sort them based on their content. Once you have the keys sorted, you generate a new LinkedHashMap where you walk your sorted list of keys and retrieve the value for each, then add those to the new LinkedHashedMap.

Answer (score 1):

Give numbers 0-6 to weekdays. Then sort them according to this numbers

There is a simple example here

[How to sort strings containing day-of-week names in ascending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429998/how-to-sort-strings-containing-day-of-week-names-in-ascending-order)

Comment: That logic will give Sunday as a first day not Monday

Comment: You don't need to use this logic exactly. It is just an example. You have to give int ID to weekdays. Then sort this ID numbers

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    public JSONArray sortWeekDays(JSONArray daysArray) {
    JSONArray sortedWeekDays = new JSONArray();

    HashMap<String, Integer> dayMap = new HashMap<>();
    dayMap.put("Monday", 1);
    dayMap.put("Tuesday", 2);
    dayMap.put("Wednesday", 3);
    dayMap.put("Thursday", 4);
    dayMap.put("Friday", 5);
    dayMap.put("Saturday", 6);
    dayMap.put("Sunday", 7);

    ArrayList<Days> weekdays = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < daysArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject dayObject = daysArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Days day = new Days(dayObject.getString("id"), dayObject.getString("weekday"));
        weekdays.add(day);
    }
    Collections.sort(weekdays, new Comparator<Days>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Days o1, Days o2) {
            return dayMap.get(o1.getDay()).compareTo(dayMap.get(o2.getDay()));
        }
    });
    for (Days days : weekdays) {
        sortedWeekDays.put(days.getJsonObject());
    }

    return sortedWeekDays;
}

    public class Days {
String id = "";
String day = "";

public Days(String id, String day) {
    this.id = id;
    this.day = day;
}

public String getDay() {
    return day;
}

public JSONObject getJsonObject() {
    super.toString();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    object.put("id", id);
    object.put("weekday", day);
    return object;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what your resulting data format should be. But supposing you've already converted it to a `List` of something like this:

```
data class Day(val id: Int, val name: String)
```

if the JSON day of the week will always be in English, you can sort them like this:

```
val sortedList = list.sortedBy { DayOfWeek.valueOf(it.name.toUpperCase()).value }
```